# facebook graph api: how to use me correctly?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

i am trying to use /me/likes/pageID the same way i used pages.isFan (REST API).
But it always uses the user/page as me for which i created the access token and not the current active user.

can't get my head around this one, any help is appreciated!

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy: With the new Graph API, the owner of the access token is `me`. You can see this by pasting an access token into the [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug).

You should be [authenticating](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication) your user and gaining an access token in their name each time they visit your site. Then use only this access token when you make your query.

This process is easiest if you use one of the [Facebook SDKs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sdks).

Comment: ok thanks so far, i also just realised that me is bound to the access token. but do i really need to create an application to "just" check if the user is fan of my own page? and even ask his authorization?

Comment: Yes you do. You need at a minimum an `app_id` to be able to authenticate a user. Facebook won't tell you anything about a user unless he gives permission to your app. Consider this your API key for Facebook. If you're working on a page tab, you don't have to do this. You can just inspect the signed_request that Facebook passes you as a query string.

Answer (score 1):

> [from comments] but do i really need to create an application to "just" check if the user is fan of my own page? and even ask his authorization?

Yes, you will need an app in any case.

If you run your app as a canvas or page tab app inside of Facebook, then you get the info if the current user liked the very Facebook fan page the app is running in(!) directly from the [`signed_request`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) parameter.

If you want to query this infor for other pages, and/or your app is running outside of Facebook, then you have to have the user connect to your app and ask permission to read his likes first, before you can get this info.

For information on the latter case, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/#user_friends_perms, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#likes

Comment: just thought maybe i can go the other way around looking at the likes of my page and see if a user is in there.

Comment: You can do that, but only from the page admin frontend on facebook.com, and only limited to the last _x_ users that liked your page. (Don’t know the actual value of _x_ right now wrong the top of my head.)